# Application error - debug exe wont run

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker, assimp

I've recently downloaded [Assimp](http://assimp.sourceforge.net/) and I've run into some troubles.

I've linked the libraries and I can get the program to compile and it runs fine in `Release mode`; however, the `Debug` `.exe` hits me with this error:

> *The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0150002). Click OK to close the application.*

[image: error]

**Some more details:**

- I'm using VS2010 with Target Machine set to `x86`.
- I am using the 32bit debug dll (`Assimp32d.dll`) that was provided, and I've tried setting runtime libraries to `/MT`, `/MTd`, `/MD`, and `/MDd` with no luck.

I read from other similar threads that I should run `Dependency Walker` on the `.exe`, but I'm not sure what the output means. I'll paste it here if this helps you guys.

> Error: The Side-by-Side configuration information for "c:\users\-----\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\AssimpTest\debug\ASSIMP32D.DLL" contains errors. The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail (14001).
>   Error: At least one required implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
>   Error: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in an implicitly dependent module.
>   Error: Modules with different CPU types were found.

Comment: What does the Application event log tell you?  If you see a message about DebugCRT missing then you need to rebuild the DLL from source using VS2010.

Comment: Just worked out how to check that. it says: Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis. Looks like i'll have to rebuild.?

Comment: Maybe your download was corrupted. You could try to re-download Assimp. If this doesn't fix the problem, recompiling might be the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than rebuilding the libraries, I downloaded a different set of libraries (it was the SDK installer) and the debug dll's from that are working perfectly.

Just in case anyone has the same problem with the same software, this was the exact name of the installer that worked for me: assimp-sdk-3.0-setup.exe

Comment: Thanks, I actually had the same problem and didn't know what to do. It is very strange. Your solution saved my problem !

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem when trying to run a 64-bit project in Debug mode when using Assimp 3.0.

What I did was go to assimp/workspaces/vc9, open assimp.sln in Visual Studio 10, convert the project, then rebuild the 32 and 64-bit dll. 
Mind you, you've got to install boost for that as well, and edit the project properties so it points to the boost directory for includes.

There's probably a way to do it using CMake as well, but I found the whole process too cumbersome to bother with in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

My solution was just to link the debug build to the release .dll files. No more issues, and I wasn't that interested in debugging the Assimp library anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, later on I downloaded the "assimp-sdk-3.0-setup.exe" file & installed it as a standard windows application.

I pointed Visual Studio Solution Include & Lib directories to respective folders from newly installed location, copied DLL to my application location. The problem was resolved. Hope this helps someone.

Cheers.